# Where does the focus@1.0.0 output come from when running an npm script?

Tags: node.js, server, nodemon

I have a simple script to start my server as follows which is defined in my package.json file.

```
"server": "nodemon server/index.js --config ../framework/config/nodemon.json",
```

When I type `npm run server` I get unexpected behaior in the terminal, as instead of running my script immediately I get an output as such:

```
> focus@1.0.0 server
> nodemon server/index.js --config ../framework/config/nodemon.json
```

What is `focus@1.0.0 server` ... and how can it run before my actual script does?

I googled `focus@1.0.0 server` and an npm package came up but I am not sure if this is relevant.

If I run the script directly:

```
nodemon server/index.js --config ../framework/config/nodemon.json
```

The output does not show up.